# material ui app bar not showing - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Recently I updated my material ui to latest versions and updated my libraries in react js.

Here's the Sample Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
class HomePage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                <div>

                    <MuiThemeProvider>
                        <div align="center">

                            <AppBar
                                title="Home Page"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </MuiThemeProvider>
                </div >
                <button id="login_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block ml0 mr0 mt32">Login</button>
}
```

In here, the normal login button gets loaded. but the Appbar doesn't get load on top of it.
It was working in old material ui library. but it fails in new one. I don't know what i am missing in it.  I checked `material-ui site` twice and more and updated all the libraries but unable to fix it. Help me with some solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [AppBar docs](https://v3.material-ui.com/api/app-bar/#appbar-api), it doesn't use title prop. 
Also, you must provide children (which will be the content of the AppBar). 
You can't see anything because you didn't provide children to AppBar

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div align="center">
          <AppBar>
            <div>Home Page</div>
          </AppBar>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

You can refer to this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-whv66?fontsize=14) example